# Reading .csv files into Python lists

Tags: python, csv

I have a lot of .csv files in a directory and I'd like to open each of them in a loop within Python such that the first .csv is read into list[0] and the second .csv is read into list[1] and so on.

Unfortunately, while my code loops through all of the .csv files, it puts all the .csv files into list[0]. How can I modify my code so that I can achieve my goal above? Many thanks.

John

Here's the code:

```
def create_data_lists():
i=0
for symbol in symbols:
    with open(symbols[i]+'.csv', 'r') as f:
        print i
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        reader.next()
        for row in reader:
            rowdata.append(row)
    data_by_symbol.append(rowdata)
    i=i+1
```

Comment: You don't need to use indexing when you are using `for ... in`, so you can replace `open(symbols[i] ...)` with `open(symbol ...)`, and get rid of all the `i`'s.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

inside the for loop, near the top, you have to refresh the list `rowdata`.  otherwise you are adding to that one forever.  have something like `rowdata = []` right after `print i`

```
def create_data_lists():

    for symbol in symbols:
        with open(symbol+'.csv', 'r') as f:
        print symbol
        rowdata = []
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        reader.next()
        for row in reader:
            rowdata.append(row)
    data_by_symbol.append(rowdata)
```

**EDIT** got rid of `i`, as i am really not using it

Comment: Adding rowdata=[] did the trick. Thanks! However, when I removed the indexing, I got the following error: "line 35, in create_data_lists
    with open(symbols+'.csv', 'rb') as f:
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list"

Comment: @johnjdc:  note the difference between `symbol` and `symbols`.  with `for symbol in symbols:` construct, you will get each element of the list symbols one by one, eliminating need of having `i` from your program.  it is just cleans the code once you are familiar with the expression.  your code looked redundant to me and others, like tjm pointed out.

Comment: also, it may make sense to make `data_by_symbol` to be a dict (`date_by_symbol={}` somewhere in your code), instead of list.  in that way you say `data_by_symbol[symbol] = rowdate` in the last line of above code.  they when you use it, you can data_by_symbol[mysymbol] to get data for mysymbol, or `for sym,dat for data_by_symbol.items()` to iterate over all symbols.  Another little feature, as keeping track of meaning of i=0, i=1 etc is not fun.

Comment: I see. I'll try to the dict structure. Thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

why not store the readers themselves in a list?

```
list_of_csv_files = []

for f in filenames:
    list_of_csv_files.append(csv.DictReader(open(f)))
```

This will store the reader itself in a list, allowing you to later on do something such as:

```
for row in list_of_csv_files[0]:
    # do some processing on the row
```

The biggest advantage of this method is taht you can then do stuff like filter columns easily, using methods such as:

```
one_row = [row["name of column heading"] for row in list_of_csv_files[0]]
two_rows = [[row["name col 2"], row["name col 2"]] for row in list_of_csv_files[0]]
```

which I suspect would be more helpful to your program than storing pre-read (and thus de-structured) csv files.

but if you really want to have all the CSV files read in and stored in a list, you will need a list of lists, I don't recommend this, it will be very memory intensive:

```
list_of_csv_files = [[]]

for f in filenames:
    list_of_csv_files.append([row.values() for row in csv.DictReader(open(f))])
```

Comment: I'm eager to learn better methods - I'm self-taught and definitely beginner level. My intention is to perform math operations on all of the .csv data that I read into the Python lists. From your post, I take it that my code will be slow using lists of lists? I chose this method simply because it's the only one I know that allows me to easily distinguish which .csv data I'm analyzing. If you have better suggestions given my goals, I'm all ears. Thanks.

Comment: Sure thing, I'll extend my answer to teach you some different techniques.